# css pushing element down in firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Basically, i have a nav bar. When the buttons are all on screen, the rest of the space is filled with a generic div.

On chrome, this works correctly. Aka, you get one neat bar along the top.

On firefox, or IE, it instead is dropped down a bit. Please see fiddle in ff or IE for example of what I mean, and chrome for what I want, if it is not obvious. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/yKKUq/2/

I have a simple header

```
           <div style="width: 100%; min-height: 50px;">
                <ul id="navlist">
                    <li><a>Button</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a>Button</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="navlistfiller" style=""></div>
            </div>
```

with css:

```
ul#navlist {
    padding:10px;
    font: bold 12px Arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline;
}
ul#navlist li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    position:relative;
    width:108px;
    height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    color:#757575;
}
ul#navlist li a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 10px;
    width:95px;
    height: 40px;
}

ul#navlist li a {
    background:red;
}
ul#navlist li a:hover {
    background:#EAEFF2;
}
ul#navlist li a.current-menu-item {
    color:#fff;
    background:#333366;
}
ul#navlist li a.current-menu-item:hover {
    background:#EAEFF2;
}
#navlistfiller {
    margin-left: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    vertical-align: top;
}
html {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    min-width: 1200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family:"Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take out the `padding` from your `ul`:

```
ul#navlist {
    font: bold 12px Arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline;
}
```

Here's your demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/yKKUq/3/

Comment: Thanks, it worked in jsfiddle, but took a while longer to get it working. It seems `display: inline;` had to go too.

Answer (score 0):

Add following CSS to #navlistfiller

display:inline-block; width:108px;

and Remove margin-left:250px;

Comment: thanks, but this would hard code the width. The idea was to fill the rest of the screen. Hence doing it the way I have.